# Python save text to variable without interpreting it

Tags: python, function, text, escaping

I am fetching a text block, and save it to a variable
Then i am splitting the text block by blank spaces, get a hotword, and save the word next to the hotword in a new variable.

The word I am trying to save is a Math function in the matlab notation.
Python always interprets the brackets and slashes in the text block before I can even process this

```
    Text block example:
    "This is a text with the hotword function x**2(3*x)+3*x"
```

The text should be splitted by blank spaces and saved to an array, but python always messes up the operators (, ) , / , - and +.

How can I escape a text without knowing what will come?

this line creates the error(twitter api):

```
    textVar= tweet['text']
```

Comment: Could you show us the code you're using that gets the error, so that we can recreate the problem and so help try to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: twitter api? Are you using `tweepy` or a different module?

Comment: I am using twython

Comment: Does python just hang, or display an error? Could you paste the error message if you get one, please?

Comment: it is no python that gives me an error, but the math libary some steps later, because the text lost its formatting

Comment: Your post currently says that a python line that gets the text from twitter is the one that throws the error, or hangs, so there's confusion there for people reading.

Answer (score 1):

Your example works fine for me on both python2.7 and python3.5

```
line =  "This is a text with the hotword function x**2(3*x)+3*x"
>>> line.split()
['This', 'is', 'a', 'text', 'with', 'the', 'hotword', 'function', 'x**2(3*x)+3*x']
```

Comment: but in some cases you also have slashes in the text

Answer (score 0):

Try using a raw string:

```
var1 = r"This is a text with the hotword function x**2(3*x)+3*x"
```

or for an example that has slashes in it:

```
var2 = r"This is text with \slashes \n and \t escape sequences that aren't interpreted as such"
```

Try evaluating var2 and you'll see python puts in additional escape sequences to turn each character into a string literal instead of an escape sequence.